# Update Mysql Table from PHP object

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am looking for advice on what is best practice when trying to update a mysql table with a php object.

Currently, I have my object with all the info it needs and I then just have php script to which publishes to the data to a mysql table. My question though is, Should I do all this `inside the Object that holds that data` I want to update or `keep the SQL stuff external to the object`?

e.g. 
object.php

```
    class Cat {
    // standard methods go here ...

    public function update_table() {
        mysqli_query("UPDATE table SET hair_colour='".$this->hair_colour."' WHERE id='".$this->id."'");
    }
 }
```

Comment: `inside the Object `

Comment: Thanks @SahilGulati is there any advice you can advise to explain why i would do the SQL updates inside the object instead of having an external script file which uses the object public access methods to fill in the bits for the SQL query?

Comment: If you are working on some Production environment of some organisation,then You should not allow querying from outside by directly sending query to `DB`, Instead you should create a such a method in which have some restricted parameter can be passed to that public method, In this way you can prevent some unwanted query to be sent directly to DB

Comment: But in case if you are doing some development for just learning purpose that will be okay, But it will not be good approach.